# Laravel PHP: Creating Data with unchecked checkbox results in 'cannot be null' error

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm developing a Laravel PHP application and one of my forms that I'm using for creating new data contains a checkbox field.  When I try to submit the form leaving this checkbox unchecked, I get a 'SQLSTATE: cannot be null' error.  I've tried using a couple of solutions to fix this problem but they haven't worked for me yet.

**Controller:**

```
public function store()
{
    $input = \Input::all();

    $validation = new Validators\Video;

    if($validation->passes())
    {
        /* Additional Controller Code for storing file path names */

        return \Redirect::route('overview');
    }

    else
    {
        return \Redirect::back()
        ->withInput()
        ->withErrors($validation->errors)
        ->with('message', 'Could not create video');
    }

}
```

The name of the field where I'm storing the checkbox data is '**video_active**'.

**EloquentVideoRepository:**

```
public function create($input, $filename, $thumb_filename)
{
    /* Need this structure in order for photos to actually be displayed. */

    $newVideo = new Video;

    /* Store Data here */

    /* Using '\Input::get()' method for accepting unchecked checkboxes */

    $newVideo->video_active = \Input::get('video_active');

    return $newVideo->save();

}
```

**Form:**

```
 @section('content')

 {{ Form::open(array('route' => 'store_video', 'method' => 'POST', 'files' => true)) }} 

 /* Additional Form Code here */

 /* Code for accepting checkbox data */

 <div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('video_active', 'Active') }}
    {{ Form::checkbox('video_active', 'Active') }}
</div> 

<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::submit('Submit', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')) }}
</div>

 {{ Form::close() }}

 @stop
```

I'm not sure why I can't accept an unchecked checkbox when creating new data in my form.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$newVideo->video_active = \Input::get('video_active');`

`\Input::get('video_active');` will return null if it hasn't been defined.

Use a ternary statement like this

`$newVideo->video_active = (\Input::get('video_active') !== null) ? \Input::get('video_active') : "";`

this is equivalent to

```
if(\Input::get('video_active') !== null) {
    $newVideo->video_active = \Input::get('video_active');
} else {
    $newVideo->video_active = "";
}
```

What I'd recommend you do is use either 1 or 0 rather than "Active" and ""
set your database column `video_active` as INT(1) and then do

`{{ Form::checkbox('video_active', '1') }}`

`$newVideo->video_active = (\Input::get('video_active') == 1) ? 1 : 0;`

then if you ever need to check if video_active is set

```
if($myModel->video_active == 1) {
    // Video is active
}
```

Comment: This solution worked for me perfectly!  Your explanation is very good too and has helped understand why the problem occurred.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

While explanation looks good, my suggestion of implementation would be:

```
$newVideo->video_active = \Input::get('video_active', false);
```